# 110 Connection time out when trying to run a PHP script

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I cannot run any PHP script on my nginx server.

I set up the usual nginx+PHP infrastructure, following this tutorial [How To Install Linux, Nginx, MySQL, PHP (LEMP stack) in Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04) .

The usual test `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` returns correctly all the PHP conf stuff. **But** when I try anything else, even a simple `echo "something"` I only get a blank page.

**EDIT**: here it is the code, it couldn't be more trivial.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo "Hello World!<p>"; ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

So I digged a bit into the logs:

The nginx/error.log says:

> 2018/12/18 17:49:32 [error] 2126#2126: *17 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: ::1, server: _, request: "GET /hello.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"

the php-fpm.log is even less explanatory:

> [18-Dec-2018 16:27:11] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1754
>
> [18-Dec-2018 16:27:11] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
>
> [18-Dec-2018 16:27:11] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms

I've installed xdebug in order to try to catch any possible hanging point, but it completes correctly to me.

here it is the `default`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

I've read other post where the same problem is observed, but I exclude I've exeeded the max number of connections.

I runned out of ideas, any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the PHP file that you tried to call that isn't working.

Comment: I temporarily used the workaround to replace nginx with apache: now it works. So it seems that nginx was misconfigured, I still wonder how.